# check false.present? in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I have an API. I want to check all the blank values in the request body and reject them. Also I have few attributes which can have either true / false (boolean) as value.

sample request body

```
{
  "data": {
      "id": 123,
       "type": "abc",
       "attributes": {
          "is_abc": false,
           "name": "gtd",
           "is_dgc": true
         }
  }
}
```

I am validating if the request body has any blank values and raise exception if any.

```
  def validate_blank_values(params)
    blank_keys = params.map { |key, value| key if value.blank? }.compact
    raise exception
  end
```

value.blank? rejects even the boolean attributes when the request has false as its value which is a valid value here. Tried

```
value.present?
```

Also behaves the same way. The problem with .nil? is it returns false for empty string also.

```
''.nil? => false
```

The problem with .empty? is

```
false.empty? => (undefined method `empty?' for false:FalseClass)
```

I want to reject the values when they are

1. blank
2. empty string
3. nil

do not reject when

1. proper value
2. false as value

Suggest me a solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use multiple conditions here otherwise it won't work.

Try below condition

```
value.present? || value.class == FalseClass || value.class == TrueClass
```

P.S. - `blank_keys = params.map { |key, value| key if value.blank? }.compact`  is not checking for nested values of `attributes`

Answer (score 3):

There more then one way:

#### Solution 1

Converting to string, striping spaces and then testing if empty would do the job

[image]

```rb
value = false
```

#### As stated by @engineersmnky With rails you can use `blank?`:

```rb
value.to_s.blank?
```

With 2 conditions

```rb
value.class == String && value.blank?
```

#### With only ruby:

```rb
value.to_s.strip.empty?
```

With Regex

```rb
/^\s*$/.match?(value.to_s)
```

With 2 conditions

```rb
value.class == String && value.strip.empty?
```

## To recursively test `json`

#### Option 1 With map and reduce

```rb
def is_empty(tmp)
  tmp.map {
    |k, v| v.class == Hash ? is_empty(v) : v.to_s.strip.empty?
  }.reduce { |r1, r2| r1 || r2 }
end

json = {
  "data": {
    "id": 123,
    "type": "abc",
    "attributes": {
      "is_abc": false,
      "name": "gtd",
      "is_dgc": true
    }
  }
}

puts is_empty(json)
```

#### Option 2 With reduce

```rb
def is_empty(tmp)
  tmp.reduce(false) {
    |result, (k, v)| v.class == Hash ? is_empty(v) : result || v.to_s.strip.empty?
  }
end

json = {
  "data": {
    "id": 123,
    "type": "abc",
    "attributes": {
      "is_abc": false,
      "name": "gtd",
      "is_dgc": true
    }
  }
}

puts is_empty(json)
```

Comment: Since this is tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails] you could just use `blank?` instead of `.strip.empty?`. [`String#blank?`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/blank%3F) *"A string is blank if it’s empty or contains whitespaces only:"*